# No GitHub label IDs?

Tags: github, github-api

We have a Github Entperprise set up locally but I can't for the life of me get label IDs using this API call: `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/labels`

I just end up getting the `url`, `name`, and `color` values:

```
{
  "url": "https://ourdomain/api/v3/repos/username/repo/labels/bug",
  "name": "bug",
  "color": "ee0701"
}
```

The [official documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/) however shows that I should be getting the `id` and `default` values as well:

```
{
  "id": 208045946,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/labels/bug",
  "name": "bug",
  "color": "f29513",
  "default": true
}
```

I'm sure I'm just missing some setting somewhere, but can't seem to find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of GitHub enterprise do you have? Is the repository you query private or public? What header values do you send with your request? Do you send authorization header in your request or not?